# Java generics wildcard entry

Tags: java, generics

In JAVA generics, why is this not valid:

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList()<?>;
```

Considering that this is valid:

```
public interface someList<?>{}
```

There are both unbounded wildcards. In my mind they are both equivalent to:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
```

and

```
public interface someList {}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>();

Comment: Basically there is no point in using the '?' wildcard, is this incorrect?

Comment: Well it means give me a list of a type, but I don't care what the type is. If you want a list that can accept any type, then you want List<Object>

Comment: `public interface someList<?>{}` is not valid either. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<?>` means any *one* type. For you as a programmer to benefit from the typechecking the designers desided that you need to supply that *one* type during instantiation.

If you want full flexibility, `List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>()` is the way to go.

The wildcard `?` is just a means of saying, yes I want generics but don't care of which type. Unlike the generic-less variant, you still get type checking and compiler warnings where necessary.

Comment: "If you want full flexibility" `List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>()` isn't any more "flexible" than, say, `List<?> l = new ArrayList<Math>()`

Comment: "Unlike the generic-less variant, ...." (More importantly) Unlike the generic-less variant, it is completely useless, because you cannot add anything to the list except `null`.

Comment: True, and somewhat unfortunate wording on my part, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Because, you cannot instantiate an `ArrayList` of *unknown* type.

You can instantiate an `ArrayList` of **raw** type.

```
 new ArrayList();
```

Or, you can instantiate an `ArrayList` of *Object* or some specific **known** type.

```
new ArrayList<Object>();
new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
class CrazyBogusUnrelatedType { }

List<?> l = new ArrayList<CrazyBogusUnrelatedType>();
```

Really. This is 100% correct, and 100% type safe. This demonstrates that you can just use any arbitrary thing in there. It also demonstrates the absurdity of doing this.

> In my mind they are both equivalent to:

Not even remotely close. They are complete opposites.

With `List l`, you can add anything to it. **With `List<?> l`, you cannot add anything to it except `null`.** So basically, the list you initialize with `List<?> l = new ArrayList()<?>;` is almost completely useless, because it is empty and since you can only add `null` to it, the only things it can ever contain are `null` elements.

This is a consequence of using a wildcard. Recall the PECS (producer `extends`, consumer `super`) rule -- you have an `extends` wildcard here (unbounded wildcard is for most purposes the same as `extends Object`), so it is only useful as a Producer. Except that there is nothing to produce -- it is empty. So why would you ever want this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to construct an object of generic type, which is nonsense.
If an object was created, it may not be of many types simultaneously, because Java doesn't model quantum world. Wildcard type indicates that type parameter is not known in advance, but it will be some concrete type when you'll have a value.

And this is not equivalent to `List l = new ArrayList();` because the latter does allow values only of static type Object, but with the help of generics you can constrain type to any reference type. (Although this information exists only at compile time)